# Symfony firewall login: How to access previous session before it gets invalidated

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am running a `Symfony 2.8` based webpage which uses the `FOSUserBundle`. When the user switches from the public part of the webpage to the private part by logging in, the session is invalided (`PHPSESSID` changes). Thus after logging in it it not possible any more to access the session which was used on the public part.

In the `Symfony` [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#invalidate-session) I found information about the `invalidate_session` in the logout config.

While it makes sense to clean the session data when logging out, I do not understand what's the reason to the same when logging in.

**Question 1:**
Is there an option to prevent `Symfony` from invalidating the session when logging in?

Even if there an option to change this behavior I would preferr to keep it this way (to prevent any unforeseen side effects). This brings us to the second question:

**Question 2:**
Is there any event or other way that can be used to access the public session before it gets invalidated during the login process?

The `Firewall.php` uses an `onKernelRequest` handler with priority 8 to run its authentication methods. Thus I tried to use my on own `onKernelRequest` handler with a higher priority to access the session first, but this did not work out. I get only access to the new session.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement an [EventSubscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) and subscribe to the events 
SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN and FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED. At that point the public session is not yet invalidated and you can get the user from the event.

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;

class YourCustomListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onUserAuthentication',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => ['onUserRegistration', -10]
        ];
    }

    public function onUserAuthentication(InteractiveLoginEvent $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $this->yourFuntionUsingTheSessionHere($user);
    }

    public function onUserRegistration(FilterUserResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $this->yourFunctionUsingTheSessionHere($user);
    }

    private function yourFunctionUsingTheSessionHere(User $user): void
    {
        // do your thing here
        // I don't know if Eventsubscribers are containeraware maybe you need to inject the container or Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface to have access to the session
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this is unfortunately not correct: On both events the session ID has already changed / the public session has already been invalidated...